# C#: ListView in VirtualMode not displaying design-time columns when adding items & subitems at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

C#: ListView in VirtualMode not displaying design-time columns when adding items & subitems at runtime?

I have a listview set up at design time with 5 columns. column[0] == empty checkbox item and the other 4 contain text.

My problem is that it 'whites out' my column headers & text when I press the button to add items to the listview from my array of listviewitem cache. Any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a handler for the RetrieveVirtualItem event?  This is the way that the ListView will ask for data to fill into the displayed values.  If you don't implement it no data will be displayed in virtual mode.

Documentation

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.retrievevirtualitem.aspx